# In MySQL how do I create JOIN within a subquery?

Tags: mysql, database, subquery, union

**Working sample using one Table**

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT
    TITLE.name, 
    (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
    (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper,
    (TITLE.value) AS Value
  FROM TITLE 
) t
WHERE 98 BETWEEN t.Lower AND t.Upper
ORDER BY ABS(98 - t.Value) ASC
LIMIT 5
```

**Desired example working with 3 tables (Needs fixed/help)**

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT
    TITLE.name, ALBUM.year, GENRE.Type
    (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
    (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper,
    (TITLE.value) AS Value
  FROM TITLE, ALBUM, GENRE 
) t
WHERE ALBUM.ID=GENRE.ID AND TITLE.ID=ALBUM.ID  
AND 98 BETWEEN t.Lower AND t.Upper
ORDER BY ABS(98 - t.Value) ASC;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ALBUM.ID' in 'where clause'

Comment: Your subquery ("t") is returning a cross-joined result set of TITLE, ALBUM, and GENRE that excludes their respective ID values. Your WHERE clause can only operate on the projection of `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is logical: your subquery creates one table `t`, and afterwords you try to refer to a table `ALBUM`. There is no `ALBUM`, there is only `t`

The quickest fix it to move the `WHERE` clause for the JOIN where it belongs: in the subquery.

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT
    TITLE.name, ALBUM.year, GENRE.Type
    (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
    (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper,
    (TITLE.value) AS Value
  FROM TITLE, ALBUM, GENRE 
  WHERE ALBUM.ID=GENRE.ID AND TITLE.ID=ALBUM.ID  
) t
WHERE 98 BETWEEN t.Lower AND t.Upper
ORDER BY ABS(98 - t.Value) ASC;
```

The query itself ain't that beautiful though... why not try this instead:

```
  SELECT
    TITLE.name, ALBUM.year, GENRE.Type
    (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
    (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper,
    (TITLE.value) AS Value
  FROM TITLE
   JOIN ALBUM
    ON TITLE.ID=ALBUM.ID  
   JOIN GENRE 
    ON ALBUM.ID=GENRE.ID 
  WHERE 98 BETWEEN Lower AND Upper
  ORDER BY ABS(98 - Value) ASC;
```

- Removed the unnecessary subquery
- Used SQL-92 style JOIN instead of SQL-89 style JOIN (cartesian product with a where clause)

Comment: @Jammin I just fixed his spelling of "cartesian" :) Konerak is the sole responsible for this answer (which I agree is the best one).

Answer (score 2):

Look at your query: you are defining a sub-query, called `T`, that does a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) between tables `TITLE`, `ALBUM` and `GENRE`. **Then** you select from that sub-query, and try to apply a `WHERE` clause over `TITLE`, `ALBUM` and `GENRE`... But those tables are not in scope anymore!

Try this instead:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT
    TITLE.name, ALBUM.year, GENRE.Type
    (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
    (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper,
    (TITLE.value) AS Value
  FROM TITLE, ALBUM, GENRE 
  WHERE ALBUM.ID=GENRE.ID AND TITLE.ID=ALBUM.ID  
) t
WHERE 98 BETWEEN t.Lower AND t.Upper
ORDER BY ABS(98 - t.Value) ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the WHERE clause to the inner query.

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT
    TITLE.name, ALBUM.year, GENRE.Type
    (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
    (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper,
    (TITLE.value) AS Value
  FROM TITLE, ALBUM, GENRE 
  WHERE ALBUM.ID=GENRE.ID AND TITLE.ID=ALBUM.ID  
) t
AND 98 BETWEEN t.Lower AND t.Upper
ORDER BY ABS(98 - t.Value) ASC;
```